# Renaming the field with special character with Simple Message Transform Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm using SMT in Splunk Sink Connector and having trouble with renaming the field. I need to change name of the field from, for example, "metric1" into "metric_name:cpu.usr".

That's how configurations of my connector look like:

```
SPLUNK_SINK_CONNECTOR_CONFIG='{
 "name": "splunk_sink_connector_1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.splunk.kafka.connect.SplunkSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "splunk.indexes": "'"$SPLUNK_INDEX"'",
    "topics":"metrics_for_splunk",
    "splunk.hec.uri": "'"$SPLUNK_HEC_URI"'",
    "splunk.hec.token": "'"$SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN"'",
    "splunk.hec.raw": "true",
    "offset.flush.interval.ms": 1000,
    "splunk.hec.json.event.formatted": "true",

     "transforms": "renameField,HoistField,insertTS,convertTS,insertEvent",

    "transforms.renameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.renameField.renames": "metric1:"metric_name:cpu.usr"",
    "transforms.HoistField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value",
    "transforms.HoistField.field": "fields",
    "transforms.insertTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.insertTS.timestamp.field": "message_timestamp",
    "transforms.convertTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.convertTS.format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm",
    "transforms.convertTS.target.type": "string",
    "transforms.convertTS.field": "message_timestamp",
    "transforms.insertEvent.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.insertEvent.static.field": "event",
    "transforms.insertEvent.static.value": "metric"
}}'
```

When I'm trying to run this connector, I get an error:

> Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value [metric1:metric_name:cpu.usr] for configuration renames: Invalid rename mapping: metric1:metric_name:cpu.usr\n

If I'm running this connector without renameField SMT everything goes without a hitch.

I understand that the problem is with ":" character in the name of the field. I've tried to wrap metric_name:cpu.usr like this:

> "transforms.renameField.renames": "metric1:'metric_name:cpu.usr'"

and like this

> "transforms.renameField.renames": "metric1:'"metric_name:cpu.usr"'"

and like this

> "transforms.renameField.renames": "metric1:"metric_name:cpu.usr""

and use escape character \ before :

"transforms.renameField.renames": "metric1:metric_name:cpu.usr"

with no positive effect.

Is it possible at all to use this SMT for renaming if I have special character in the name?
Or maybe there is some handy workaround?
It seems that this use case should be rather common, but I haven't found anything on the web.
Will be very grateful for advice.

Comment: Hi Jennika, welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you edit your question to include the full Single Message Transform configuration that you're using.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Thank you for attention! I've edited my question with full configuration. BTW I'm a huge fan of your work :)

Comment: Is this problem solved? I also have special character in the name.